# Is there a straight forward way to install and configure WebdriverIO with Internet Explorer 11 and Egde support

Tags: webdriver, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, webdriver-io

I went through all the docs and posts about Webdriver IO that I could find and I couldn't find a straight forward way to install and **configure WebdriverIO with webdriver for Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 10**.

All explanations were either unclear or required deep interventions in the Windows, like adding changes to the Windows registry.

Could someone give clear and concise instructions on how to install and configure WebdriverIO with Internet Explorer 11 and Edge on Windows 10, please?

I am testing a corporate software solution that a lot of corporate users are still using on IE11. Also it is important to test on Edge too, as it is the current Windows default web browser.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

To use the WebdriverIO with webdriver for Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge, first, you have to install the [InternetExplorerDriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver) and [Edge Driver](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/), then refer to the following article and use the [Selenium Standalone service](https://webdriver.io/docs/selenium-standalone-service.html) to configure it.

[Cannot configure MicrosoftEdge with webdriverio v5+](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/3196)

[selenium-standalone-service cannot find IE driver](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/4688)

Since, this issue is related to webdriverio, if you have any further question about webdriverio, you could also post your question in the [WebDriverIO issue forum](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues).